# call lambda functions from list

Tags: python, list, lambda

If I have a list containing a lambda function, for example:

```
a = [lambda x: x * 2]
```

how could I call this lambda function to a list:

```
b = [1,2,3,4]
```

so that it could have the result as:

```
result = list(map(lambda x: x * 2,  b))
```

and get:

```
[2,4,6,8]
```

Further, what if a contains two lambda functions, for example:

```
a = [lambda x:x * 2, lambda x: x-1]
```

How could I call these functions to list b without using for loop or list comprehension but use map()?

I hope someone could help me with it!

Comment: You might want to have a look into list comprehensions: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_list_comprehension.php

Then it would be something like `result = [a(x) for x in b]`.

Comment: What result do you expect in the second case?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
result = list(map(a[0],  b))
# [2,4,6,8]
```

since the lambda function is the first element of `a`

For the second function it's the same thing

```
result = list(map(a[1],  b))
```

If you want to apply all functions in one line

```
[list(map(a[i],b)) for i in range(len(a))]
#[[2, 4, 6, 8], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: What if I don't want to use list comprehension but use a nested map function?

Comment: And you want the same output as the list comprehension? If so, I don't think you can do it

Answer (score 0):

In the special case of a single lambda wrapped in a list, do

```
result = list(map(a[0], b))
```

But there are no special cases in python. So for the general case, you can either have a flat list:

```
result = [f(x) for f in a for x in b]
```

or a nested one:

```
result = [[f(x) for f in a] for x in b]
```

You can reverse the sort order of the lists by swapping the loops over `a` and `b`.

You can even go as far as using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get the flat case (again with `a` and `b` interchangeable to change the order of the result):

```
result = [f(x) for f, x in itertools.product(a, b)]
```

Comment: What if I don't want to use list comprehension but use a nested map function?

Comment: @YiyangChen. A list comprehension is to all intents and purposes a faster (and in my opinion cleaner) way to do `list(map...)`, combined with `filter`. You can use whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the lambda functions in the list no matter how many elements stored in it:

```
a = [lambda x:x * 2, lambda x: x-1]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for func in a:
     # apply each function on b and turn the results to list:
     print(list(map(func, b)))
```

If you want to store each result:

```
a = [lambda x:x * 2, lambda x: x-1]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
results = []

for func in a:
    results.append(list(map(func, b)))
```

Comment: What if I don't want to use for loop but use a nested map function?